# Do we really need to add an extra node in Johnson's algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, graph

In [Johnson's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%27s_algorithm) you create a new node and then add zero weight edges from this node to all other nodes as a first step in the reweighting procedure.  But why can't we do the same thing without adding a new node? That is pick an arbitrary node in the graph and add zero weight edges from it to all other nodes, run Bellman Ford's algorithm to compute the reweighting that is needed and proceed as before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to introduce a negative cycle that way. Given the graph

```
   -1
a ---> b,
```

choose `b` as the root.

Comment: @Anush I should mention that, if you implement Bellman--Ford for Johnson's algorithm, you don't need to augment the graph this way; just start it where every vertex is at distance zero. You also don't need the parent pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Another reason why Johnson's algorithm needs an additional node `s` is that this node ensures that **every** other node in the graph is reachable through Bellman-Ford's algorithm (i.e. every node `u` carries the minimum weight from `s` to `u`). If this cannot be guaranteed, reweighting is not possible and hence, the algorithm won't work. Note that adding a new node `s` doesn't introduce a (new) negativ-weight cycle.